# Cannot figure out specific Git syntax to "push" only a single file

Tags: git, push

It might not matter but I'm attached to the GitLab server with the SSH URL, rather than the HTTP(S) URL.

On the GitLab server, the path to the Project is (I'm gonna fake part of this for security purposes):
`Group/Group/Project/subdir = Engineering/Bladelogic/Scripts/test`

The closest I've come to success, in specifying a single file and getting a successful "push", is this:

```
$ git push origin development {commit-hash}:refs/{commit-hash}
```

But there are two problems:

1. The above command (successfully) pushes everything that is presently committed and not yet pushed, rather than only the 1 file whose hash I specified.
2. Even though it effectively pushes something, I still get the following screen-output, which includes the partial errors indicated below:

```
Counting objects: 17, done.  
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (12/12), 1.19 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.  
Total 12 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)  
remote: error: refusing to create funny ref 'refs/62ce94830fa2753ef8ca3bb28d74dbe0cea39ead' remotely  
To git@<FQDN>:Engineering/Bladelogic/Scripts.git  
   9e722dd..62ce948  development -> development  
 **! [remote rejected] 62ce94830fa2753ef8ca3bb28d74dbe0cea39ead -> refs/62ce94830fa2753ef8ca3bb28d74dbe0cea39ead (funny refname)**  
**error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitrepo.oneabbott.com:bts-tools-engineering/tssa/BladeLogic-Scripts.git'**
```

Is there a way to push only 1 presently-committed file and, if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not understanding what Git is. Git does not deal in files. It deals in commits. Commits are the only thing you can push.

Comment: Okay, matt.  But, if I do 3 separate commits, each of which is only a single (different) file, then, when attempting to push only 1 of those 3 commits, that must be the same thing as pushing the 1-and-only file that was included in that particular commit.  (Right?)

Comment: @JohnReedAvery you can only push a commit *including* all its predecessors. So if you have commits 1, 2, 3 (1 being the oldest), you can push only 1, or 1 and 2, or 1, 2, 3 – but not only 2 or only 3 or only 2 and 3 or only 1 and 3.

Comment: Wrong. There is no such thing as a commit containing only one file. Every commit is a snapshot of your entire project.

Comment: **Hey, mkrieger1:**  If you are convinced that what you say is correct then please provide syntax.  

**Hey, matt:**  It sounds as though, if I want to push only the latest update-&-commit of only 1 file --EVEN if that DOES include "the entire project"-- I need to always commit only 1 file at a time and then more-or-less-IMMEDIATELY "push" that single commit.  Period.  Make sense?

Comment: I don't understand what "provide syntax" means.

Comment: **Hey, mkrieger1.**  Oh, sorry.  Please note the command-line syntax that I gave at the top of this post/question, which I said did not behave correctly for me.  If I can push only the oldest 1 or the oldest 2 or all 3 of the latest 3 commits, I still need to know precisely what command-line syntax to use.  When I have done **git push origin development <source>:<destination>**, I get an error saying that the "src refspec" is wrong or not recognized.  Make sense now?  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to push only a single file.  Git's protocol is designed around finding a set of commits and tags that are in common and sending the objects that one side has and not the other.  That necessarily involves walking the history, which practically requires commits or tags.

If you want to make a changes to only a single file, you can put those changes in a separate commit and push only that.  For example, if you want to create a  new commit out of the state of file `foo` on branch `branch`, you could do `git checkout branch:foo` and then commit, which would create a commit that contained only that file.

But as for pushing just a single file, that's not possible.  A tag or commit is going to be needed.

Comment: Okay.  I'm still new to Git/GitLab; so, I have not yet gotten to the point of even trying to understand "tags" yet.  I'll look at that, though I note that there is some argument, below, about the correct syntax for applying at tag and, if there is a syntactically-wrong way to express the tag-assignment command, I'll be sure to find it without breaking a sweat.  ;-)

Comment: However, some other posts (on a few different sites) have said that pushing 1 or 2 or 3 (etc) files can be done with something like the following syntax:  $ git  push  origin development  <source>:<destination>
So, I am confused as to how/why their different answers can have such similar command-line syntax but still all be wrong.  If they are wrong, how did they all come up with that specific syntax?  I'm not meaning to be argumentative.  I'm simply still *VERY* confused!  <big sigh>  :-/

Comment: That syntax can push a single commit, not a single file.  You can technically push a single blob (single file) _if_ you specify the destination such that it contains at least three components, such as `refs/tags/foo`, and that will work since it's a lightweight tag, but it's effectively useless in almost all contents.

Comment: Thanks, **bk2204**.  Unfortunately, I'm still *VERY* fuzzy about how precisely to express "refs", if it's not literally the 4 characters "refs", which I assume that it is not.  <another-big-sigh>  I've not yet been able to find anybody's post or web-page --or any man-pages-- that **truly** clarify precisely what "refs" means, in different contexts --i.e., different specific examples.  I've been having **MUCH** difficulty in finding posts in which specific concrete examples are given for various different Git elements, such as "refs" and "refspecs".  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* want to push just one file, tag that file and push the tag:

```
git tag myfile master:path/to/that.file
git push origin myfile
```

and then people fetching that tag will get just the one file -- which Git's convenience commands won't really know what to do with, but Git itself? Sure.

As a quickie testcase:

```
$ cd `mktemp -d`; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/jthill/tmp.wKE9Fx3zCz/.git/
$ echo test > test.file; git add .; git commit -m demo
[master (root-commit) fe3c6c5] demo
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.file
$ git tag myfile master:test.file
$ git init `mktemp -d`
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/jthill/tmp.PXlls8ZgK3/.git/
$ git push $_ myfile
Enumerating objects: 1, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 46 bytes | 46.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To /tmp/jthill/tmp.PXlls8ZgK3
 * [new tag]         myfile -> myfile
$ cd /tmp/jthill/tmp.PXlls8ZgK3
$ git show myfile
test
$
```

Comment: OP: to be clear: (a) "push just one file" is language that people who're trying to do or avoid something else would use. What are you really trying to do here? and (b) it's worth repeating: almost none of the "normal" Git commands will know what to do with that tag.

Comment: This is not valid tag command syntax. You cannot give it a path, only a commit or branch.

Comment: @siride you're wrong about that.

Comment: I read the whole man page and it says nothing about file paths. Furhermore, it doesn't make sense. A tag attaches to a commit, so there would be no way to tag a file.

Comment: @siride The doc says `git tag … <object>` right up top, and tagging arbitrary objects has always worked. And among the arbitrary objects you can tag are the objects file paths refer to.

Comment: It's the object part that I missed. It looks like the tag can point to trees or blobs as well. I still can't see the use case, especially given the confusion that can arise (it would be weird to check out a tag pointing to a blob). I would not recommend it here. The OP is probably trying to do something else and we should figure that out first.

Comment: @siride the use case is when you've got just one file you want to publish independently of the main development. Metadata calculated by a post-receive would be one example.

Comment: Okay.  Regarding the specific syntax to your above-suggested tag-assignment command:  It's not clear to me as to where that "path/to/that.file" starts.  If my local Project-Directory (wkg-dir) is "/home/jravery/gitparent/<project-name>/test/", and the "test" subdir is where "that.file" is located, then precisely where does the "path/to/that.file" start, on the command-line???  Do I start all the way up at "/home" or do I start with the "<project-name>" directory or what???   Thanks!  --JRA

Comment: @JohnReedAvery after the `:`, use whatever `git ls-files --full-name` shows you for the file, i.e. the path from `:` starts at the work tree root. About the only common command other than fetch and push that can handle tagged blobs is show.   Push will duplicate the tag by default, but fetch won't, it uses the core-command FETCH_HEAD. So `git fetch repothathasit myfile; git show FETCH_HEAD >path/to/wherever.you.want`

Comment: Aaaah.  Okay, **jthill**.  Thanks.  I *think* I understand what you are saying but I don't have time to test it out right now.  I'll give it a try, later, and respond over the weekend or next week.  Thanks again!  --JRA

Comment: Hey, **jthill**.  I just now tried your recommended syntax, for applying a tag, and it does not work.  Here are the details and the steps that I performed:  
**(1)**  Committed-file-to-push = chickenlips.

Comment: Let me start again:  

**(1)**  Committed-file-to-push = chickenlips  

**(2)**  Path to that file = [...]/<local-project-dir>/averytest/chickenlips  

**(3)**  $ cd  [...]/averytest  

**(4)**  $ git  ls-files  --full-name  ./chickenlips  -->  averytest/chickenlips  

**(5)**  $ git  tag  tagtest  master:averytest/chickenlips  
**fatal: Failed to resolve 'master:averytest/chickenlips' as a valid ref.**  

Any ideas?  Thanks.  --JRA

Comment: Note that I tried the "git ls-files --full-name" command, for the chickenlips file, from a couple of different subdirs, and I tried the "git tag" command from a couple of different subdirs.  Also: when I was sitting in the averytest subdir, I tried the "chickenlips" argument each with and without the leading "./".  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnReedAvery added a demo, it's time to play spot-the-differences with what you were doing.

Comment: Hey, **jthill**.  Thanks for the demo.  Actually, I suddenly figured out what I had done wrong, without even looking at your demo.  My "**git tag**" command needed to reference "development", rather than "master".  When I made that change, it simply worked.  

I even did a bit more reading about tags, so that I was able to assign an **annotated tag** to the chickenlips file.   And I did what appeared to be a successful **push** of that tag.  

However, ... [see next comment] ...

Comment: However, I figured out that this technique also does not allow me to push an actual single-commit to the remote-repository.  The GitLab GUI has a note that says "Tags give the ability to mark specific points in history as being important".  So, I think I'm gonna give up on this quest and reframe my conception-of and expectations-of the "push" feature.  

Thanks anyway, everybody!!!  --JRA